# mySql Subquery Answers Check Final Exam Questions

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I'm having some doubts regarding these answers of mine, would greatly appreciate if you guys can clarify if im right or wrong,

## Questions:

An employee may be assigned to more than one project and a project may have many employees. Consider the following relational schema and write `SQL` statements for the below queries.

```
Employees (empID, empName, empDOB, empAddress, salary, deptID, jobID)

Assignments (empID, projID, assignedDate, completionDate, status)

Projects (projID, projDescription, startDate, endDate, projType)
```

(a) Display the names of employees who were born before 31st Jan 1980 and assigned a ‘Office Complex’ type project, sort results in ascending order of name. (5 marks)

(b) Retrieve the empIDs who are assigned at least two (2) projects. (5 marks)

## Answers:

```
(a) SELECT empName FROM Employees WHERE empDOB < '31-01-1980' AND projType = (SELECT projType FROM Projects WHERE projType = 'Office Complex') ORDER BY empName; 

(b) SELECT empID FROM Employees GROUP BY (SELECT projID From Projects) HAVING COUNT(*)>1 ORDER BY empID;
```

I feel the answer for the second question may be wrong.

Comment: in regards to the b): Have a closer look at the table "Assignments". This one stores valuable data which will help you.

Comment: i am trying to figure it out , also in answer (a) , isnt it wrong becasuse im getting FROM Employees and Relating the WHERE Clause to the Projects Table for Project Type?

Comment: Tagging a MySQL question with the sql-server tag takes 5 marks off of your exam grade:-)

Comment: (b) SELECT empID FROM Assignments GROUP BY projID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

Comment: @DanGuzman I'm Sorry , Just thought it would be fine to tag it with SQL Related Tags ,Sincere Apologies mate.

Comment: You should make yourself familiar with `JOIN` operations. You should first `JOIN` the tables you need to get the data from and afterwards specify you selection.

Comment: Looks alot better! Best way to get used to writing queries would be to set up a database, build your schema and execute queries. Here you can use an online mysql database for testing/ playing around: http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Thanks! @stb
SELECT Employees.empName FROM Employees,Assignments,Projects WHERE Employees.empID = Assignments.empID AND Assignments.projID = Projects.projID AND projType = 'Office Complex' AND empDOB < '31-01-1980' ORDER BY Employees.empName;     

Is this a better answer for (a)

Comment: You are getting a hang! Another advice: Consider using the `JOIN` operator in combination with `ON`. This makes your queries more readable and it's commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

For part a), I'd join the tables to match up employees with the project type:

```
 SELECT empName 
 FROM Employees 
 INNER JOIN Assignments ON Assignments.empID = Employees.empID
 INNER JOIN Projects ON Assignments.projID = Projects.projID
 WHERE empDOB < 31-01-1980 AND projType = 'Office Complex' 
 ORDER BY empName;
```

As it stands, your statement attempts to find projType = 'Office Complex' in the Employee table, where it doesn't exist.

For the second question, everything you need is in the Assignments table:

```
SELECT empID, COUNT(projID)
FROM Assignments
GROUP BY empID
HAVING COUNT(projID) > 1
```